# Xcode 10 iOS firebase firestore SDK -- multiple command produce gRPCCertificates.bundle error in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I am getting multiple command produce gRPCCertificates.bundle

> Multiple commands produce '...iphoneos/gRPCCertificates.bundle':
>
> 1)
>   Target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates' has create directory command with
>   output '.../iphoneos/gRPCCertificates.bundle'
>
> 2) Target
>   'FirebaseFirestore-gRPCCertificates' has create directory command with
>   output '....iphoneos/gRPCCertificates.bundle'

Here is my Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'FireCheck' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FireCheck

 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

I have already tried clean, deleting derived data, deintegrating and reintegrating pods, nothing works
I am using Xcode 10.

It only happens when I do build and achieve ... normal run/debug works

It also only happens in macOS 10.14 (18A391) not in previous version of the macOS (High Sierra)

More information I have added here
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `pod update`

The issue is now fixed with the release of version 0.0.5 of gRPC-C++.

More details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2102

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for an update on the Github project, you can temporarily use the previous version of Firestore.

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '5.12.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that didn't use CocoaPods to install RNFirebase and is getting this error, navigating to the `Build Phases` -> `Copy Build Resources` in Xcode and removing the duplicate `gRPCCertificates.bundle` file manually worked for me.