# Multiple command produce gRPCCertificates.bundle error in new Firestore Version

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I came across the same issue in [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406947/xcode10-ios-firebase-firestore-sdk-multiple-command-produce-grpccertificates), and the answer mentions that the issue has been resolved since version 0.0.5 of gRPC-C++ has been out, however, I can confirm even after running pod update and my gRPC-C++ is updated to 0.0.7, I still cannot acrhive my project without getting the `multiple command produce gRPCCertificates.bundle` error.

Here is my [Podfile.lock](https://pastebin.com/LC6G8MN8) after the latest `pod update` I ran, and here is the [Podfile](https://pastebin.com/EvxmzDWP) itself.

Full error here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove version locking in the Podfile so that FirebaseFirestore will update to the latest version when you run `pod update`:

```
 pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```